# Como se puede modificar el lenguage del EXE generado por electron-builder?

Tags: electron

Estoy tratando de usar **electron-builder** para generar un ejecutable EXE de mi applicacion (electron)
Aunque aun no lo logro 100% bien, he generado un exe, y en sus propiedades, puedo ver "Language: English(US)".

Como puedo setear electron-builder para que genere otro lenguage como propiedad del ejecutable, por ejemplo Espanol?

Notas:
Estoy usando

```
"build":{
   win":{
     "target":["portable"],
     "icon": "icon/myicon.ico"
  }
}
```

pero el unico recurso que pude encontrar para hacer algo asi fue usando `"target":["nsis"]`
en [nsis options](https://www.electron.build/generated/nsisoptions)